# If check box is check display div but hide previous open div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" data-related-item="title1">
<span class="caption">Title</span>
<div class="hidden">
<h2>Title</h2>
<input type="text" id="title1">
<span class="caption">Lorem</span>
</div>
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" data-related-item="title2" checked>
<span class="caption">Title</span>
<div class="hidden">
<h2>Title</h2>
<input type="text" id="title2">
<span class="caption">Lorem</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function evaluate(){
var item = $(this);
var relatedItem = $("#" + item.attr("data-related-item")).parent();

if(item.is(":checked")){
    relatedItem.fadeIn();
}else{
    relatedItem.fadeOut();   
}
}
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluate).each(evaluate);
```

This was about this post: [if check box is checked display div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712251/if-check-box-is-checked-display-div/32250722#32250722)

I would like to ask how do I use this code but every time you click another checkbox it hides the previous div and opens a new one. Just showing one div/content at a time instead of showing both open. Thanks.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zgrRd/5/

Comment: $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluate).each(evaluate); is doing this to work on each checkbox  instead you call it for particular checkbox

Comment: Please edit your question title. The title should be the issue, not the expected outcome

Comment: similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650913/using-checkbox-as-radio-button you need to uncheck a box when you check another one, like the radio button.

Comment: Something like accordion? https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `change` instead of `click` function and inside evaluate function, add the following line at the start

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked',false).trigger('change');
```

Watch here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgrRd/435/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want only one `<div>` open at a time, which should correlate to a checkbox. I interpret this, that you also only checkbox checked at a time, so all other checkboxes wold need to be unchecked.

Solution 1: Use radio buttons

Solution 2: Uncheck all checkboxes and re-check the current one.

The solution for showing the `<div>`s is based on solution 2. Just hide all `<div>`s first and then show your related `<div>`. Give all your `<div>`s a certain class (e.g. `class="toggling"`) or name to be used as a selector for closing all.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var relatedItem = $("#" + item.attr("data-related-item")).parent();
    $('.toggling').fadeOut(); //hide all
    relatedItem.FadeIn(); //show the current one
});
```